# How to delete a (calendar or gmail) task using google appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to manage calendar / gmail tasks within a google appscript project.
All the integration work is done (Tasks API activation, authorization,...)

I have managed to create a tasklist and a task in this code, but can't figure out how to delete a task using the google Tasks API with the google appscript.

The reference offers few samples, including uses of the list and the create methods, but none for deletion. The Rest API reference give few more samples with java, PHP, Python and .Net implementation of the API, but still none for google appscript.

Here's what I've tried :

```
Tasks.Tasks.delete(tasklistid, taskid);
```

But the above code can't be saved in the appscript editor (due to the use of the javascript reserved word "delete" I guess).

Any clue on where I could find a complete google appscript reference for the Tasks API or any "delete Task" sample ?

Comment: look at the apps script issues page and vote for it. is the highest voted request.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I try the "my best guest" way of resolving the issue and found the replacement google used to avoid the javascript "delete" key word :

```
Tasks.Tasks.remove(taskList.id, task.id);
```

Comment: @nop77svk it does answer the question (albeit not very well). Guillaume please expand your answer to at least include **why** your answer will resolve the issue.

Comment: Since I could'nt find an exhaustive API reference for this Google Apps Script Service, this method is undocumented.

Comment: I've used my intuition to find out this method and several tests to check its validity. 

Empiricism is all I got for the why... Do I need to explain that in my post ?
Sorry but that's my first post on SO and I don't know the "good practices".

By the way, could you explain me why it does answer the question albeit "not very well" ? Did I miss something ?

Comment: Not a problem. Have a quick look at [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before answering in future, all of the necessary guidelines are there. Also, in my honest opinion, a great answer includes __1.)__ an explanation of what you are changing/doing __2.)__ a sample of code to show how/where you made a change and __3.)__ what the new/expected result is. Obviously each question (and therefore each answer) is different, but if you try to stick to these guidelines, you should be fine.